# How to keep frames provided by VideoCapture in OpenCV

Tags: video, opencv, load

I want to write a function using opencv which reads a Video file grabs single frames and stores them lets say in std::vector>. Problem turns out at the end of function, I've got images in vector of vectors, but when a release VideoCapture all the data is gone.

```
vector<Mat>load_single_video(string path)
{   
    vector<Mat> one_video_vector;
    Mat video_img;
    VideoCapture Temp_video_capture(path);
    Temp_video_capture.read(video_img);
    while (!video_img.empty())
    {           
        one_video_vector.push_back(video_img);      
        Temp_video_capture.read(video_img);
    }

    Temp_video_capture.release();

    return one_video_vector;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read):

> **Note:** OpenCV 1.x functions `cvRetrieveFrame` and `cv.RetrieveFrame` return
>   image stored inside the video capturing structure. It is not allowed
>   to modify or release the image! You can copy the frame using
>   `cvCloneImage()` and then do whatever you want with the copy.

Although we are using the new OpenCV 2.x API, `VideoCapture::read()` is actually a wrapper for `cvRetrieveFrame()`. And just as the notes said, you have to make a copy of the frame.

```
one_video_vector.push_back(video_img.clone());
```

Comment: The solution is not exactly as you said. But your suggestion helped me.